# Combining multiple django apps into one view, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django project with multiple apps that I need to combine and render as a single page. I have the following sections of code:

One of the views I'm trying to aggregate with other views:

```
class ResourceList(generic.View):
    model = Submissions
    template_name = 'url_list.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resources = Submissions.objects.all()
        return render_to_string(self.template_name, {'object_list': resources})
```

The view I'm trying to use to aggregate my apps:

```
class Index(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwars):
        renderable = {
            'content': ResourceList(),
            'login': LoginView() # I don't care about the LoginView at the moment.
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', renderable)
```

url_list.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} <!--I've removed this, it did nothing -->
{% block content }
    {{ object.url}}
<ul>
    {% for resource in object_list %}
    <li> {{resource.url}} {{ resource.id }} {{ resource.rating }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <title>HI</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% block login %} login {% endblock %} {% block content %} content {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that it just renders "login content" when I go to the test url I've got set up for the page. If I change `render_to_string` to `render_to_response` and go to the url I have set up to render just that view everything works perfectly. What's going on here?

Things I've tried:

- removing the extends and block definitions from url_list.html, doesn't work.
- passing `request` to my object instance in `renderable`, I get a `__init__ expects 1 argument, got 2` error
- defining `__init__` on ResourceList to accept a `request` argument. It just renders the placeholder content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this like that. Views are glorified functions.
They have a single entry point (`dispatch()`) that is invoked by Django internals, and invokes the correct method on itself, depending on the HTTP method (here, `get()`).
Casting the view to a string will just display its name, not call it.

If you want to aggregate the behaviors of multiple view, you have several options.

- you could extract those behaviors in functions, and have your actual views call those functions.
- you could make mixins, and mix them into the views.

For instance:

```
from django.views.generic.base import ContextMixin

class ResourceListMixin(ContextMixin):
    def get_resource_list(self):
        # we put it in a separate method to allow easy overriding
        return Submissions.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['resources'] = self.get_resource_list()
        return super(ResourceListMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Now you can mix that into any view, and it will automagically know about`{{ resources }}`. For instance:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class IndexView(ResourceListMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    # nothing else here, we leverage the power of Django's
    # TemplateView - it will do everything by itself
```

Then the `IndexView` view will render the `index.html` template, and it will be able to do `{% for resource in resources %}`.

Comment: You'll want to check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/ I believe. It describes Django-provided views you can extend in a very modular way.